# emberjs attributes not getting saved on form submit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this form in a component:

```
<form class="" {{action "saveEdit" on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="text" id="name"value=person.name  }}
  {{input type="date" id="dob" value=person.date_of_birth}}
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

When it gets submitted I user `sendAction` to send it to the route:

```
   saveEdit: function () {
      this.set("isEditing", false);

      this.sendAction("action", this.get("person"));
    }
```

Where I save it:

```
saveEdit: function (person) {
      person.save();
    }
```

However, only the name gets saved,

This does not work:

```
  saveEdit: function () {
      this.set("isEditing", false);
      var dob= $("#dob").val();
      var person = this.get("person");
      person.set("date_of_birth", dob);
      this.sendAction("action", person);
    }
```

When I console.log the `person` object I get:

```
_data: Object
date_of_birth: null
id: "1"
name: "Joey"
```

The name updates but the `date_of_birth` gets set to null.

I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Where is your model definition?

Comment: Why are you using IDs and doing `$("#dob").val()`?  Handlebars does this binding for you, you know?

Answer (score 0):

It was the in the model definition. I set one of the attributes to "date" but the form was sending back a string. I just set the attribute to "string" and it works fine.